# Boot time is very slow

Tags: boot, 20.04, performance, services

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 and it is super fast on my PC. It is not the dual boot. My PC specs are:

```
CPU: Intel Pentium E5700@3GHz
Graphics: Intel G41(Onboard Graphics)
HDD: 250gb
Ram: 4GB + (4GB Swap)
```

But the boot times are very slow. It takes about 1 min to boot. At first it was about 30sec but now it is almost 1 minute. I checked boot time with `systemd-analyze time` and it gave me these results:

```
systemd-analyze time
Startup finished in 5.929s (kernel) + 51.893s (userspace) = 57.822s
graphical.target reached after 51.826s in userspace
```

And I did check with `systemd-analyze blame` and it showed like this:

```
systemd-analyze blame
32.833s plymouth-quit-wait.service
24.428s apport-autoreport.service
11.315s dev-sda7.device
7.112s accounts-daemon.service
6.533s dev-loop8.device
6.489s dev-loop3.device
6.415s dev-loop4.device
6.050s dev-loop0.device
5.991s dev-loop2.device
5.534s dev-loop1.device
5.332s dev-loop5.device
5.055s dev-loop6.device
4.944s dev-loop7.device
3.806s avahi-daemon.service
3.625s switcheroo-control.service
3.613s thermald.service
3.515s systemd-logind.service
3.513s wpa_supplicant.service
3.079s ufw.service
2.880s gpu-manager.service
2.688s snapd.service
2.652s udisks2.service
2.367s rsyslog.service
2.327s grub-common.service
2.252s e2scrub_reap.service
2.237s preload.service
1.855s systemd-udevd.service
1.629s grub-initrd-fallback.service
1.615s apparmor.service
1.350s systemd-modules-load.service
1.348s gdm.service
1.260s fancontrol.service
1.097s systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
1.069s systemd-resolved.service
1.019s lm-sensors.service
1.004s systemd-sysctl.service
987ms systemd-journal-flush.service
935ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
895ms systemd-journald.service
801ms systemd-random-seed.service
781ms fwupd.service
761ms systemd-timesyncd.service
686ms upower.service
537ms plymouth-read-write.service
515ms snap-core18-1705.mount
489ms keyboard-setup.service
456ms systemd-sysusers.service
412ms snap-core18-1880.mount
398ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
379ms kerneloops.service
372ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-128.mount
355ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-24.mount
341ms systemd-remount-fs.service
318ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d34\x2d1804-36.mount
315ms pppd-dns.service
305ms modprobe@drm.service
230ms snap-snap\x2dstore-415.mount
222ms user@1000.service
220ms NetworkManager.service
219ms polkit.service
188ms console-setup.service
173ms systemd-rfkill.service
168ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1506.mount
168ms snap-snapd-8542.mount
131ms dev-mqueue.mount
131ms systemd-update-utmp.service
130ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
129ms dev-hugepages.mount
129ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount
128ms snap-snapd-7264.mount
120ms kmod-static-nodes.service
93ms dev-disk-by\x2duuid-ee5aecd0\x2d8f8b\x2d461c\x2db8e0\x2d401f0dd6f584.s wap
86ms plymouth-start.service
80ms colord.service
78ms hddtemp.service
62ms setvtrgb.service
57ms systemd-user-sessions.service
31ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
25ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service
16ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
14ms alsa-restore.service
10ms rtkit-daemon.service
9ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
4ms sys-kernel-config.mount
4ms snapd.socket
```

Here the critical-chain results also:

```
systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.
graphical.target @51.826s
└─multi-user.target @51.826s
  └─kerneloops.service @18.921s +379ms
    └─network-online.target @18.847s
      └─network.target @18.847s
        └─wpa_supplicant.service @15.333s +3.513s
          └─dbus.service @15.088s
            └─basic.target @14.995s
              └─sockets.target @14.994s
                └─snapd.socket @14.990s +4ms
                  └─sysinit.target @14.898s
                    └─swap.target @14.898s
                      └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-ee5aecd0\x2d8f8b\x2d461c\x2db8e\x2d401f0dd6f584.swap@14.804s +93ms
                        └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-ee5aecd0\x2d8f8b\x2d461c\x2db8e0\x2d401f0dd6f584.device @14.801s
```

So how can I reduce my boot time?

Edit: Output of dmesg | grep -i error

```
dmesg | grep -i error
[    0.761799] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT, Index (0x0FFFFFFFF) is beyond end of object (length 0x4) (20190816/exoparg2-393)
[    0.761843] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.IDE1.GTM due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[    0.761850] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.IDE1.CHN1._GTM due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20190816/psparse-529)
[    0.798345] RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
[    9.912364] EXT4-fs (sda7): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[ 3014.858735] mt7601u 1-6:1.0: Error: MCU response pre-completed!
[ 3017.471090] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Attempt to CreateField of length zero (20190816/dsopcode-133)
[ 3017.471122] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.IDE1.RATA due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_VALUE) (20190816/psparse-529)
[ 3017.471131] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.IDE1.CHN1.DRV1._GTF due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_VALUE) (20190816/psparse-529)
[ 3017.473543] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Attempt to CreateField of length zero (20190816/dsopcode-133)
[ 3017.473569] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.IDE1.RATA due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_VALUE) (20190816/psparse-529)
[ 3017.473577] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.IDE1.CHN1.DRV0._GTF due to previous error (AE_AML_OPERAND_VALUE) (20190816/psparse-529)
```

Comment: The `apport-autoreport.service` thing suggest there may be some errors. Take a look at `dmesg | grep -i error`. Also, IMHO, it is unlikely a 10 year old PC will boot in 30 sec. A more reasonable time is what you get, or about 90 seconds.

Comment: Output of above command: https://ibb.co/J57M8n8

Comment: That is a picture of a some text, not the output. Kind of fuzzy, hard to see. Why not add the text itself, same as you did with other outputs?

Comment: @mikewhatever You can see the output that I posted in my thread.

Comment: Thank you, much better, I can also copy paste to search. I'd try to investigate the ACPI errors. What kind of storage device is there? Is it SATA or PATA?

Comment: @mikewhatever It is SATA hdd.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things to mention:

> I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 and it is super fast on my PC.

Your other computer is most likely equipped with better hardware - in particular, a faster/newer CPU (Pentium E5700 is from 2010) and a faster disk (probably an SSD instead of HDD).
SSD will make a huge difference, and we can't expect fast boot times from a 10 year old Pentium as well.

> At first it was about 30sec but now it is almost 1 minute.

It's normal for boot times to increase after installation. There were probably some drivers and additional software installed.

Boot time being 1 minute is completely reasonable for your PC running Ubuntu. If you'd like a more lightweight option, check [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.me/) (literaly **L**ightweight **Ubuntu**). If you'd like to speed up your computer, buy an SSD. If you want to tweak your Ubuntu to make it boot faster, check the running services in your systemd-analyze blame report and disable the ones you don't need.

Note: *plymouth* service is the splash screen, and it does not actually take 30sec of your boot time. From what I understand, that's just the time the service is waiting to display splash screen.

Comment: I had tried Lubuntu also, but it was little slow on my PC so I installed Ubuntu with Gnome and it is fast. So I decided to stay in Ubuntu.

Comment: Lubuntu is Ubuntu base + LXLE, the name itself has nothing to do with lightweight. Also, in my experience, it is not normal "for boot times to increase after installation". Something is wrong if that happens. Additional drivers and software should not affect boot time.

Comment: @mikewhatever I might be wrong on what lubuntu means, although lubuntu is presented as being lightweight version of ubuntu. I can't find any specific answer on what the 'L' stands for. As for drivers, they do increase boot time if they're loaded.

Comment: p.s. the 'L' in LXDE desktop environment in Lubuntu also stands for lightweight ...

Comment: Well, consider that Xubuntu and Ubuntu-Mate are also considered lightweight, but there aren't any L's in their names. :~)

Comment: Thank you but I am okay with Ubuntu.

Comment: It was just a suggestion, noone here is trying to push you into something. Rather consider the points about your hardware and disabling unnecessary processes and services.